# Laravel: how to create resource that depends on multiple models

Tags: php, json, laravel-5

I need to create a resource that should collect information from multiple models.

At the moment I'm creating a regular resource:

```
$movieResource = new MovieResource($movie);
```

Inside of `MovieResource::toArray()`:

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    $this->initRepos(); // initializing used repositories as static fields

    $movieData = [ // transforming model to resource
        'title' => $this->title,
    ];

    $this->attachSounds($movieData); // Uses two unrelated tables
    $this->attachUrl($movieData);    // Uses one unrelated table
    $this->attachAnotherInfo($movieData); // Uses one unrelated table

    return $movieData;
}
```

`MovieResource` class is used in a few different places in the project. In order to not duplicate logic I decided to inject repositories inside resource.

In some places `MovieResource` is used extensively, that's why used repositories are initialized as static properties of `MovieResource` class (to avoid multiple instances initialization)

Such structure however has some limitations: testing is almost impossible, because static methods can not be mocked. Resource class should be as simple as possible, but now it is overloaded.

I'm aware that current solution is far from ideal that's why I'm asking for you help, advice or experience share on how current solution can be enhanced.

Comment: Use [repositories](https://deviq.com/repository-pattern/) instead of concrete models. Inject whatever models you need into a "master" repo and go from there.